# ¿Cómo agregar los elementos de una lista de caracteres en una matriz de nxm

Tags: python

¿Cómo puedo agregar los elementos de una lista de caracteres en una matriz de nxm?

Tengo este codigo en python.

```
key = raw_input('Key: ') #Pedimos la clave
text = raw_input('Text: ') #Pedimos una cadena de texto
text_c = list(text)   #Pasamos la cadena a una lista de caracteres
while ' ' in text_c:  #quitamos los espacios
  text_c.remove(' ')      
#caculo de las columnas y renglones
columns = len(key)              
rows = int(math.ceil(float(len(text_c)) / float(len(key))) )
#Definicion de una matriz
matrix = []
for i in range(rows):
    matrix.append([])
    for j in range(columns):
        matrix[i].append(None)
```

Lo que quiero hacer es rellenar la matriz con los caracteres de la lista.

Por ejemplo el usuario escribe: 
  key:HOLA
, texto: esto es texto

El programa genera una matriz de 3 renglones por 4 columnas
y quiero rellenar esa matriz con los caracteres de texto, de esta forma:

```
[e,s,t,o]
[e,s,u,n]
[t,e,x,t]
[o,none,none,none]
```

Gracias por sus respuestas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prácticamente ya lo tenías terminado. Siguiendo tu ejemplo, esto es lo que faltaba:

1. Definir una variable para ir contando los caracteres

   ```python
    pos = 0
   ```
2. Incrementar la para cada iteración

   ```python
    pos += 1
   ```

   Que, a medida que avanzan los 2 bucles, va incrementándose de a 1
3. Agregar el caracter de esa posición como nueva columna en la fila `i`

   ```python
    matrix[i].append(text_c[pos])   #pero da error si pos excede el tamaño de text_c
   ```
4. ... excepto cuando ya no quedan más caracteres

   ```python
    matrix[i].append(text_c[pos] if pos < len(text_c) else None)
   ```

---

#### Código

```python
import math

key = raw_input('Key: ') #Pedimos la clave
text = raw_input('Text: ') #Pedimos una cadena de texto
text_c = list(text)   #Pasamos la cadena a una lista de caracteres
while ' ' in text_c:  #quitamos los espacios
  text_c.remove(' ')      
#caculo de las columnas y renglones
columns = len(key)              
rows = int(math.ceil(float(len(text_c)) / float(len(key))) )
#Definicion de una matriz
matrix = []
pos = 0

#Agregar los caracteres
for i in range(rows):
    matrix.append([])
    for j in range(columns):
        #Agregar en la fila i una nueva columna con el siguiente caracter
        #     o None si ya no quedan
        matrix[i].append(text_c[pos] if pos < len(text_c) else None)
        #Incrementar el contador de caracteres
        pos += 1

print matrix
```

**Resultado:** `[['e', 's', 't', 'o'], ['e', 's', 'u', 'n'], ['t', 'e', 'x', 't'], ['o', None, None, None]]`

<kbd>[Demo en ideone.com](http://ideone.com/CKQxPL)</kbd>

---

Cabe aclarar que hay formas más compactas o *pythonic* de hacer esto mismo, pero me pareció la mejor opción para explicar el tema.

Comment: Muchas gracias.Pude resolverlo de forma similar.

Comment: Super bien la solución, me ayudo mucho a un problema similar que tenia. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Pude resolverlo de la siguiente forma. Por si a alguien le llega a servir, este es el codigo:

```
aux=0
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        if aux<len(cadena_caracteres):
            matrix[i][j] = cadena_caracteres[aux]  
            aux+=1
```